# backup project copy

Tags: .net

how do you make a copy of a project in .net?

Comment: do you mean backup up to a version control system?

Comment: well i basically have to merge two projects with SVN, so if that doesnt work out, i need a backup of the project to back to.

Comment: what about the version of the project that is in version control? Cannot you not just revert to that if the merge doesn't work out?

Comment: its not checked into SVN...the other project (which needs to be merged) is

Answer (score 4):

<strike><kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> :)</strike> Couldn't resist, sorry.

You just need to copy all of the project files over into a new directory.

Comment: +1 Love the kbd tags.  Never used them before, are they always styled like that or does that credit belong to SO?

Comment: stackoverflow styling - `kbd {-moz-background-clip:border;-moz-background-inline-policy:continuous;-moz-background-origin:padding;background:#EEEEEE none repeat scroll 0 0;border-color:#CCCCCC #AAAAAA #888888 #BBBBBB;border-style:solid;borderwidth:1px 3px 3px 1px;color:#000000;padding:2px 4px;white-space:nowrap;}`

Answer (score 0):

Create a new project and then copy files from one to the other (using normal windows copy/paste)

Answer (score 0):

I just copy all visual studio files to a different directory.