# backup not made

Tags: .net

i did not make a back up of a project and SVN Merged it using Tortoise with another project. It was not checked into SVN so there was no version to revert back to. Is there any way of recovering that project back?

Comment: This forum provides a functionality called "accept answer" by the way.

Comment: -1 for not following advice: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1793791/backup-project-copy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your unsaved project was `X` and the project you merged (+) it with was `Y` then you are left with `X+Y=XY`. Therefore a diff (-) between `XY` and `Y` should be your original `XY-Y=X`.

Try this:

- Backup your working copy
- Commit it to branch `X`
- Switch to project `Y`
- Merge two different trees from `Y` to `X`
- If you now generate a diff/patch of your working copy it should be what you want.

I am a bit of a cowboy with SVN so there is probably a *much* better way to do this. Also this is untested and off the top of my head, so the first step (make backup) is really important.